# Como passar variavel session em um input do tipo hidden no php

Tags: php

Tenho um formulário e preciso passar o valor da sessão via metodo post.
Estou usando o código abaixo, mais não esta funcionando.

```
<input type="hidden"  name="cod_usuario" value="<?php session_start(); $_SESSION['login']; ?>" class="input-medium" id="txtFuncionario" title="Nome do Funcionário"/>
```

Comment: obs: session_start(); tem que estar no inicio do arquivo por padrão... posta o código todo amigo pf

Comment: Obrigado.
O código é muito grande.
Coloquei no http://jsfiddle.net/2L7zLmoc/

Comment: O texto está na linha 100.

Comment: Não funciona como? Retorna algum erro? Fica em branco? Qual o objectivo de enviar o id da sessão em um POST? Explique melhor, do jeito que está só você entende.

Comment: Preciso passar o usuário que está logado. Está ficando em branco.

Comment: Porque não faz isso no "FormCadOS.php" (Está no action do seu formulário)? Obs.: sempre que fizer referência a um utilizador nos comentários, utilize o @ (arroba), irá aparecer uma lista com os nomes de quem comentou, escolha o destinatário. Só assim o utilizador irá receber um alerta e perceber que você fez referência ao que ele comentou.

Comment: @Filipe. Pode ser dessa forma, mas eu testei e não estava dando certo.
Efetuo o teste passando 1 direto para variável e o sistema inseri no banco de dados normalmente.
Então eu coloco o abaixo e não inseri nada no banco.
`'<?php
session_start();

    require '../php/funcao_mysql.php';
    
$cod_os = $_POST['N_OS']; //1 - Número da OS
$cod_usuario = $_SESSION['login'];`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro coloque no inicio do seu arquivo.

```
<?php
session_start();
?>
```

Segundo, por mais que seja uma variável da sessão, pra ela ser populada em um campo do formulário, é necessário dar um `ECHO` nela. No seu caso:

```
<input type="hidden" id="txtFuncionario" 
name="cod_usuario" value=" <?php echo $_SESSION['login']; ?>" >
```

Comment: @Filipe. Efetuei os testes com a orientação acima e não funcionou.

Comment: fabricio, verifica se voce setou o valor da sessão corretamente, nessa sua página do formulário, tenta fazer o seguinte: de um 'echo var_dump($_SESSION);' depois do session_start(); e poste aqui o resultado...
LEMBRANDO... E NÃO MENOS IMPORTANTE session_start(); tem que estar em todas as páginas, ou arquivos de php que voce necessitar verificar ou transportar as variaveis de sessão

Comment: Fiz o que você me pediu e retornou o resultado abaixo:
`'array(2) { ["login"]=> string(6) "djalma" ["senha"]=> string(3) "123" }`'
Estranho que não grava no banco mas se eu colocar `'$cod_usuario = 1;`' vai gravar.

Comment: bom, recapitulando, voce da um `echo var_dump($_SESSION);` no formulario onde quer que apareça o login em um campo hidden, e aparece isso: `array(2) { ["login"]=> string(6) "djalma" ["senha"]=> string(3) "123" }` correto? E quando voce da um echo na variavel `$_SESSION['login'];` não aparece nada?

Comment: Desculpa @Marcelo. Imprimiu o resultado anterior e imprimiu o nome da pessoa logado só que não salva no banco.
Estou usando mysqli.
Tem ideia do que pode ser?
Fiz assim para testar:
`'echo var_dump($_SESSION); 
echo "<br />";
echo $_SESSION['login'];`'

Comment: essa outra pergunta tá no escopo dessa pergunta? se não eu recomendo criar um novo tópico expondo qual o problema que tá acontecendo agora, com mais detalhes e mais abertamente... provavelmente tem relação ao modo que voce ta tentando salvar...

Comment: Qual pergunta? **Tem Ideia do que pode ser?** Desculpa, mas realmente eu não sei e acho que as pessoas buscam o forum, não para que alguém faça por vc e sim porque já se esgotaram o número de tentativas e ele não consegue.
Se eu tenho um formulário e eu abro um post por causa de um problema no formulário e ele não salva no banco, eu não vejo a necessidade de um novo post.

Comment: Velho, o assunto inicial era "Como passar variavel session em um input do tipo hidden no php", aparentemente esse problema já foi resolvido... voce tem outro problema no formulario, nada mais justo do que criar outra duvida que tenha um assunto mas haver com o que busca..... isso aqui acaba virando assunto off-topic